# sonar runner SocketTimeoutException when running

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

i was working with sonar and everything was working just fine. then after a month or so not using it i started receiving the following exception when running the sonar-runner.bat

i am using the embedded h2 db server and use the default ports.

```
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\sonar\sonar-runner-2.2.2\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: c:\eclipse\workspaces\projName\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "iw_IL", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: c:\eclipse\workspaces\projName\.sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:00.553s
Final Memory: 1M/242M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1392)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.ok(HttpRequest.java:1417)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:83)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.downloadVersion(ServerVersion.java:49)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.version(ServerVersion.java:40)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerVersion.is35Compatible(ServerVersion.java:64)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:59)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:57)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:71)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:89)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1485)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1390)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:697)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:640)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2300)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:1903)
        at org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest.contentType(HttpRequest.java:2308)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:79)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: i have a similar issue. did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to: `sonar-runner-2.3/conf/sonar-runner.properties`
2. Uncomment the line: `#sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000`
3. Replace `localhost` with your IP and save the file!
   example:`sonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.12:9000`

Comment: I did the same thing but still I'm getting the same issue. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Default port used by sonar is 9000,may be this has been used by some other application on your system.

Change your listening port in 
sonarqube-4.2/conf/sonar.properties, 
sonar-runner-2.3/conf/sonar-runner.properties

Restart sonar
sonarqube-4.2/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh restart

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and found that I have installed my sql but forget to reset mysql password.

I found my mistake by accessing logs under /logs/access.log

So logs will surely help you to figure out problem.

Answer (score -2):

This error is triggered by a SonarQube plugin that I'm not aware of : "kevinsawicki". I guess removing this plugin should fix your issue.

Comment: kevinsawicki is just a part of a name of one dependency of sonar-runner - com.github.kevinsawicki:http-request (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-runner/blob/9188444d5e4ceda8ed655dd2149b58c113ab914e/sonar-runner-impl/pom.xml#L14)